# How would I automate this in selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

I am a newbie in Selenium Webdriver (Js), trying to learn some basics, being majorly stuck on this example:

I am trying to automate googling "Diablo 2 Resurrected days until release" and then printing the days remaining to the console from google.

The part I struggle with is printing the days left to my console. I have a feeling that the problem is, that the element I'm trying to use .getText() on is not available yet when webdriver tries to find it, however using driver.sleep() nor implicitlyWait does not work for me for some reason. I use xpath and css as a selector, neither did work for me. Here is my code:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until, WebDriver} = require("selenium-webdriver");
const { elementIsVisible } = require("selenium-webdriver/lib/until");
require("chromedriver");



let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();



driver.get("https://google.com");


// this clicks on cookies accept button
driver.findElement(By.css("#L2AGLb > div")).click();

driver.findElement(By.css('body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input')).sendKeys('Diablo 2 Resurrected days until release');

driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]')).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]')).getText().then(txt => {
    console.log("Do D2R releasu zbývá: " + txt)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error!', err);
});
```

Here is the error:

```
error! NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[7]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]"}
```

Edit: Solved! Here is the working code

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until, WebDriver} = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");

let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

async function howManyDaysTillDiablo2ResurrectedRelease() {
    await driver.get("https://google.com");
    await driver.findElement(By.css("#L2AGLb > div")).click();
    await driver.findElement(By.css('body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input')).sendKeys('Diablo 2 Resurrected days until release');
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]')).click();

    let ele = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("div[data-attrid*='calculate:how_many_days_away'][role='heading'] div")), 10000);
    let foo = await ele.getText();





    await driver.findElement(By.css("div[data-attrid*='calculate:how_many_days_away'][role='heading'] div")).getText().then(foo => {
        console.log("Do D2R releasu zbývá: " + foo)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('error!', err);
    
    
})};

howManyDaysTillDiablo2ResurrectedRelease();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xpath` that you are using, looks like you got from dev tools. (and it's an absolute xpath, not relative xpath)

As you have mentioned you are a beginner, I would recommend you to learn css selector and xpath and try to write your own. Meanwhile :-

You can use the below css :

```
div[data-attrid*='calculate:how_many_days_away'][role='heading'] div
```

and use it like this :

```
driver.findElement(By.css("div[data-attrid*='calculate:how_many_days_away'][role='heading'] div
")).getText()
```

**Update :**

```
let ele = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("div[data-attrid*='calculate:how_many_days_away'][role='heading'] div")), 10000);
let foo = await ele.getText();
```

Comment: What is the expected output ? is it `60 days` ?

Comment: yes 60 days as of now. Thanks for patience, I tried what you wrote and I got the error: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[data-attrid*='calculate:how_many_days_away'][role='heading'] div"} what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you put some sleep before this and see if that works ?

Comment: With driver.sleep(5000); above the driver.findElement I still get the same error as previously

Comment: @JaroslavValášek : Can you try the updated code from above, that is now with explicit waits

Comment: Hey thank you very much, I managed to edit the code correctly and I put it under an async function and it works now, thanks again!

Comment: Great, then you should really edit this answer with what exactly worked and close this ticket as well. so that, it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this.

Comment: Thanks, done as u told me. One last thing, what is the best way for me to get the selector that you used? I am always getting it from the dev tools, is there any better way that you used? Thank you

Comment: the only one better way I know is to learn xpath axes, unfortunately there isn't any tool that can provide us reliable selector, here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: for css https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp